# How do I print a board with letters on it

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array where I ask the user for its dimensions, for e.g. 4x4. Then I want to print out ABCD to label the row and ABCD vertically to label the column.

I'm attempting to do it but not sure how to loop it properly.

```
void printBoard (char board[26][26], int size);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int size; //board size is even and not exceeding 26

printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

char boardgame[size][size];
printBoard (boardgame, size);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void printBoard (char board [26][26], int size) {

for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < size; size++) {
        printf("%c", board['A'+ row]['A'+ col]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you calculate this index `'A'+ row`?

Comment: How do I increment letters then? like A B C D

Comment: You are not incrementing any letter those are the indexes of the array and they are very much of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use letters as array indices like that. 'A' + row will not work. 'A' is a character who's ASCII code is 65, so you're saying 65+row.

Secondly,

```
printf("%c", board['A'+ row]['A'+ col]);
```

is doing nothing as far as labeling the rows and columns is concerned. Here you are attempting to print out the contents of the array itself. I am assuming you want a row at the top to label the columns, and a column along the side to label the rows, if that's the case you are executing too many print statements.

Also, when it comes to incrementing letters you should learn about ASCII.
http://www.asciitable.com/

As you can see, 65 is ASCII for a capital A.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%c",65);
    return 0;
}
```

This code will print out an A. I think this could spark an idea for how to approach your letter incrementing problem.